# Breaking out of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am new to python and programming and having difficulty breaking out of a while loop that calls a few functions. I have tried a variety of different options but they all end the same, well they don't end it just keeps running. I am only on here because I have really researched and tried for a long time to fix this. Below is some of the code where you can see there might be confusion with a function. I am not posting the full program just the last part. Thank you for any assistance while I learn. This is also my first time posting, I've been using stackoverflow for the past year dabbling.

```
def main():
        choice = input('''Hello,
Would you like to do basic math or return an average?
Please select 1 for basic math and 2 for average and 3 to quit:

''')
        if choice == '1':
            print(performCalculation())

        elif choice == '2':
            print(calculateAverage())

        elif choice == '3':
            print(main())

j = 0
k = 0
while j < 3:
    print(main())
    while k == 3:
        break
print('All Done!')
```

Comment: The loop will exit when `j` becomes 3, which will never happen because you don't seem to increment or assign to `j` in the code you have posted

Comment: Please remember that break applies to the recent while, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
j = 0
k = 0
while j < 3:
    print(main())
    while k == 3:
        break
print('All Done!')
```

to

```
j = 0

while j < 3:
    print(main())
    j += 1
    
print('All Done!')
```

The reason your while loop never breaks is because you have `while j < 3:`, but you never change the value of `j`, so if it was smaller to begin with, it will forever be smaller.

Also, `k` will never equal to `3`, and even *if* it will, the `break` statement within *that* `while` loop will only make *that* while loop terminate, not the main one.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, when I run this it will end the loop if I go in order, as in my 1st selection is 1, 2nd is 2 and then it ends. However, when I run this and immediately select 3 it simply asks me again, "Hello, Would you...." and so on until I go in order. That is what stumps me. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have several basic mistakes here. I'll go in order of your program execution.

#### You aren't incrementing your loop variables.

You've started your loop variables with `j` and `k` (why not `i` and `j`?) set to zero, and are looped based on the value of these variables. Since they are never incremented, your loop never hits an exit condition.

You can increment the variables with `j += 1`, and `k += 1` at the end of the respective loops.

#### Your loops are "unpythonic"

These would typically be written as my example below. You don't need to declare `i` separately, or increment it here. Python handles that for you.

```py
for i in range(0, 3):
    ...
```

#### You're printing a function that doesn't return anything.

Your main function doesn't have a return value, so calling `print(main())` is nonsense. You can replace this with simply `main()` unless you change `main()` to have some kind of `return "foo"` statement.